# Dynamic reading from file & displaying on form load

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text files named  `sQue.txt` containing single words in each lines (each word in each line) and `sObj.txt` also containing single word in each line (but no. of entries are more in this file than in sQue.txt).

Now, I have a blank form in which I want to read both the above files & display them in a manner such that:

1. Each entry from sQue.txt file gets displayed in separate labels in the form
2. All the entries of file sObj.txt are put in a CheckedListBox & this CheckedListBox appears for each label displayed in point 1. above.

Example:

`sObj.txt contains 3 entries aaa, bbb & ccc (vertically i.e each in new line).`
`sQue.txt contains 5 entries p,q,r,s & t (vertically i.e each in new line).`

Now, when the form loads, 3 labels are seen with texts aaa, bbb & ccc. Also 3 CheckedListBoxes are seen containg `p,q,r,s & t` in each box.

Can it be done? I'm trying to find a solution with no luck yet.

Please help.

Till now all I have is

```
Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim queue As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sQue.txt")
    Dim objects As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")

    For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
    'create labels here
       For j=0 to objects.Count - 1
       'create CheckedListBoxes
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: with no luck ? .. but i'm sure you have some pieces of code to show ..

Answer (score 0):

It is easily done:

```
Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim theAppDirectory = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)

    Dim queue As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(theAppDirectory & "\que.txt")
    Dim objects As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(theAppDirectory & "\obj.txt")

    Dim top As Integer = 10
    Dim left As Integer = 10
    Dim I As Integer = 0
    Dim J As Integer = 0

    Dim aLabel As Label
    Dim aListCheckBox As CheckedListBox

    Dim aPanel As New Panel
    aPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    aPanel.Top = 0
    aPanel.Left = 0
    aPanel.AutoScroll = True

    For I = 0 To queue.Count - 1
        aLabel = New Label
        aLabel.Text = queue(I)
        aLabel.Top = top
        aLabel.Left = left

        aListCheckBox = New CheckedListBox
        aListCheckBox.Top = top
        aListCheckBox.Left = left + 100
        For J = 0 To objects.Count - 1
            aListCheckBox.Items.Add(objects(J), False)
            top += 20
        Next J

        'add event handlers here

        aPanel.Controls.Add(aLabel)
        aPanel.Controls.Add(aListCheckBox)
    Next I

    Me.Controls.Add(aPanel)
End Sub
```

This assumes that you want the files to be in the same directory as the executable.

Also no event handlers are added. You will need to determine what event handlers you want and add them when you create the controls.