# Reading from text file & displaying on form load

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text files named  `sQue.txt` containing single words in each lines (each word in each line) and `sObj.txt` also containing single word in each line (but no. of entries are more in this file than in sQue.txt).

Now, I have a blank form in which I want to read both the above files & display them in a manner such that:

1. Each entry from sQue.txt file gets displayed in separate labels in the form
2. All the entries of file sObj.txt are put in a CheckedListBox & this CheckedListBox appears for each label displayed in point 1. above.

Example:

`sObj.txt contains 3 entries aaa, bbb & ccc (vertically i.e each in new line).`
`sQue.txt contains 5 entries p,q,r,s & t (vertically i.e each in new line).`

Now, when the form loads, 3 labels are seen with texts aaa, bbb & ccc. Also 3 CheckedListBoxes are seen containg `p,q,r,s & t` in each box.

Can it be done? I'm trying to find a solution with no luck yet.

Please help.

Till now all I have is

```
Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim queue As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sQue.txt")
    Dim objects As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")

    For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
    'create labels here
       For j=0 to objects.Count - 1
       'create CheckedListBoxes
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a single XML file instead. Create a format that is easy to parse (think ahead about potential usage). It should work better in long term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776469/dynamic-reading-from-file-displaying-on-form-load BTW, it's your own question.

Comment: You realize that your example is exactly opposite of what you state in beginning of your question? What exactly are you wanting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a groupbox you can use the text property as your label, and add a checkedlistbox to the groupbox with the items you want.  This code will do that:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim NewForm2 As New Form2
        NewForm2.Show()
        Dim sObj() As String = File.ReadAllLines("sobj.txt")
        Dim sQue() As String = File.ReadAllLines("sQue.txt")
        For Each s As String In sObj
            Me.Controls.Add(MakeNewGB(s, sQue))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
Public Module Module1
    Friend WithEvents NewGB As System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    Friend WithEvents NewCLB As System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
    Public NextColumn As Integer = 0
    Public Function MakeNewGB(lbl As String, clbItems() As String) As GroupBox
        NewGB = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        NewCLB = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox()
        NewGB.SuspendLayout()
        'GroupBox1
        '
        NewGB.Controls.Add(NewCLB)
        NewGB.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(NextColumn, 0)
        NewGB.Name = lbl
        NewGB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(126, 210)
        NewGB.TabIndex = 0
        NewGB.TabStop = False
        NewGB.Text = lbl
        '
        'CheckedListBox1
        '
        NewCLB.FormattingEnabled = True
        NewCLB.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(6, 19)
        NewCLB.Name = "clb" + lbl
        NewCLB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(103, 184)
        NewCLB.TabIndex = 0
        NewCLB.Items.AddRange(clbItems)
        NextColumn += NewGB.Size.Width + 10
        Return NewGB
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: your code does almost what I wanted only problem is the checkedlistbox items are switched with label items & vice versa. Needed a minor tweak & got fixed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: In continuation to your post I have one more request. I have a button, which on clicking should save the NEWGB.Name of all the group boxes that occur & also the NEWCLB items for that NEWGB.

Comment: What exactly do you need? All that information is available as part of the Controls collection.  `Me.Controls("GBName")`, will return the groupbox with that name.  Then `Me.Controls("GBName").Controls("CLBName")` will return the checkedlistbox.  Of course there are a great many other methods and properties you can access as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look like this. But i am not sure what the purpose of it is.

```
Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim queue As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sQue.txt")
    Dim objects As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\sObj.txt")

    For i = 0 To queue.Count - 1
    'create labels here
       Dim label as new Label
       label.Text = queue(i)
       Dim chklst as new CheckedListBox

       For j=0 to objects.Count - 1
         'create CheckedListBoxes
         chklst.Items.Add(object(j))
       Next
       Me.Controls.Add(label)
       Me.Controls.Add(chklst)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code creates one label (the first entry in sQue.txt) & one checkedlistbox (with all items of sObj.txt). I got the output I wanted using tinstaafl's code above. Thanks for the help though !